# How to call ES6 module function from onclick

Tags: javascript, html, ecmascript-6

I have some HTML with a button whose `onclick` event triggers a JavaScript function.

I need to achieve the same behavior when the JavaScript function is an ES6 module function.

I have a simple example:

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="./js1.js"></script>
  <script type="module" src="./js2.js"></script>
  <script type="module">
    import { Es6Module3 } from "./js3.js";
    document.querySelector('#myFunction3').addEventListener('click', Es6Module3.myFunction3);
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <button onclick="myFunction1(1)">button1</button>
  <button onclick="Es6Module2.myFunction2(2)">button2</button>
  <button type="button" id="myFunction3">button3</button>
</body>
```

It's also reproduced at https://jsfiddle.net/avnerm/jho6qgLu/18/

When clicking *button1*, the function *myFunction1* in *js1.js* is called, and the value that is passed in is printed properly into the console. good!

But when clicking *button2* I get a message:

> ReferenceError: Es6Module is not defined

At some point I was able to trigger a module function (the use case of *button3*) by setting an event listener, but it's not working now and I don't know how to pass a parameter into the function in this implementation.

In my case, I need to be able to pass in a parameter.

**How can I call a ES6 module function from the onclick attribute, and pass a parameter to it?**

---

EDIT:
@CertainPerformance, My original html code involves jinja2, which spans the code 3 times (3 groups with ids: 1, 2, 3)

I used your pattern, and it created 3 buttons (button1, button2, button3) with 3 event listeners. When I click on each button I can see in the log the appropriate group id.

**This works for me perfectly!**

I just wanted to confirm that this is the way to deal with html, jinja2, and es6.

Thanks!

```js
class Es6Module2 {
    static myFunction2 = function(val) {
        console.log('BEG myFunction2');
        console.log('val'); 
        console.log(val); 
    };
};

export { Es6Module2 };
```

```html
{% block content %}

<div class="admin-view-groups">
    {% for group in groups %}
        <button id="button{{group.id}}">Download Group</button>
        <script type="module">
         import { Es6Module2 } from './Es6Module2.js';
         document.querySelector('#button{{group.id}}').addEventListener('click', () => {
             Es6Module2.myFunction2({{ group.id }});
         });
        </script>
    {% endfor %}
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The only way to do it would be to assign the imported module function to the window object so that it can be referenced by the inline handler:

```
  <script type="module">
    import { Es6Module2 } from "./js2.js";
    window.Es6Module2 = Es6Module2;
  </script>
```

But that defeats the purpose of modules.

Regardless, inline handlers should [never, ever](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59539045) be used. They have way too many problems, including this one (requiring the function to be called to be in the global scope). Best to avoid them and use `addEventListener` instead, to add the listener properly.

If you want to add a listener which calls a function with a parameter, then just call the function with the parameter in the listener:

```
import { fn } from './script.js';
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', () => {
  fn('foo');
});
```

Comment: Can you show how to use the addEventListener and pass in param from the html to the javascript function?
I was able to hook up the button3 to the function myFunction3, but it's not working now and I don't know what is wrong. Also I couldn't pass a parameter using this approach.
Thanks